# Odd behaviour of Graphics.SmoothingMode

Tags: c#, graphics, antialiasing

I created a `Bitmap` and draw a simple `string` and `Rectangle` on it. Furthermore I set `graphics`'s `SmoothingMode` to `AntiAlias`.

```
orgBitmap = new Bitmap(250, 250);

using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(orgBitmap))
{
    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(30, 30, 150, 200);
    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, rect);

    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Green, 5))
    {
        graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
    }

    graphics.DrawString("Test Test Test Test", new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 35, 35);
}
```

This shows some unexpected behaviour, because not all the graphics have been antialiased. Somehow the antialiasing is limited to all the graphics located in the `Rectangles`'s area. The `string` drawn outside this area did not get antialiased and I wonder why. Is this a bug or how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because you are drawing the text over an area that has not been initialised - so there's no background colour with which to antialias - it's treating it as transparent (although the background does come out as white, as you can see).

You can easily fix this by calling `graphics.Clear(Color.White);` immediately before doing the rest of the drawing.

Then it will come out anti-aliased, like so:

[image]